(NOBRIDGE) LOG Bridgeless mode is enabled and JavaScript logs will be removed from Metro in React Native 0.77
I created a new React Native project with the following versions:
"dependencies": {
"react": "18.3.1",
"react-native": "0.76.3"
}
The project built successfully, but after indexing, I noticed the following logs and warnings:
BUNDLE  ./index.js
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  Bridgeless mode is enabled
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  Running "pickyassistcrm" with {"rootTag":11,"initialProps":{},"fabric":true}
INFO
 JavaScript logs will be removed from Metro in React Native 0.77! Please use React Native DevTools as your default tool. Tip: Type 'j' in the terminal to open (requires Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge).
Why is this Info showing up?
Is there anything I need to do to remove it or make changes to avoid this log in the future?

What "warning"? I see an info log. An update to v0.77 should remove this message.
